# Amazon Custom AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

If I create a custom AMI for an EBS backed EC2 instance after installing numerous applications and making lot of config changes to the EC2 instance like IP Tables, httpd.conf file etc...

Will the custom AMI image capture all those config changes and/or installed applications so that I can use it to launch exact functioning copy of the Custom AMI originating EC2 Instance?

Comment: Please don't cross-post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445077/amazon-custom-ami

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

I had to enter more characters for this to be posted, but really, that's it. It's a snapshot of the node you created.